# XSL shows children values

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an XML like this:

```
<Cities>
  <City id="1">
    <![CDATA[Paris]]>
    <Airport>
      <![CDATA[CDG]]>
      <Code value="par-cdg" />
    </Airport>
  </City>
</Cities>
```

And when I try to display the City value "Paris" it shows "ParisCDG".

To display I use: `<xsl:value-of select="//xft:City[@id=1]"/>`

Does anyone knows how can I only display current node value and not it children ?

Comment: trying to fix that :p

Comment: there it is and thanks to whomever corrected it ;)

Comment: its happening because of the behaviour of xsl tht it concates the strings.

Comment: does this work? (note the single quotes)  <xsl:value-of select="//xft:City[@id='1']"/>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, because xsl:value-of return so called "string value" which is concatenation of text content of an element and all of its descendants. Try following:

```
<xsl:value-of select="//City[@id=1]/text()"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<xsl:value-of select="$Cities/City[@id=1]/text()"/>
```